# Add comma after first word starting with a capital letter

Tags: r, regex, stringr, stringi

As the title says. I have a bunch of names and I need to add a comma after the first word that starts with a capital letter.

An example:

```
txt <- c( "de Van-Smith J", "van der Smith G.H.", "de Smith JW", "Smith JW")
```

The result should be:

```
[1] "de Van-Smith, J" "van der Smith, G.H." "de Smith, JW" "Smith, JW"
```

I have mainly been trying to use `gsub()` and   `stringr::str_replace()`, but am stuggling with the regex, any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use -

```
sub("([A-Z][\\w-]+)", "\\1,", txt, perl = TRUE)

#[1] "de Van-Smith, J"   "van der Smith, G.H." "de Smith, JW"       "Smith, JW"
```

where `([A-Z][\\w-]+)` captures a word which starts with upper case letter and has `-` or any number of word characters following it.

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
sub('\\b([A-Z]\\S+)', "\\1,", txt)
[1] "de Van-Smith, J"     "van der Smith, G.H." "de Smith, JW"        "Smith, JW"
```

Answer (score 1):

Another `sub` option

```
> sub("([A-Z].*)(?=\\s)", "\\1,", txt, perl = TRUE)
[1] "de Van-Smith, J"     "van der Smith, G.H." "de Smith, JW"
[4] "Smith, JW"
```